# "Graph Individualization"[ reference request]

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

**Context:** I am studying Weisfeiler Lehman method(WL method) and have clear idea about 1 and 2 dimensional WL method.  I was wondering about the individualization process described below-

**Individualization:**

$G$ is a $r$ regular graph .  $n$ th vertex of $G$ is $v_n$. 
All vertices which are not adjacent to $ v_n $ create a sub-graph $C_1$.
  All vertices adjacent to $ v_n $ create a sub-graph $, C_2 $. 
A vertex of $C_2$ is $ v_{n-1}$.

Using same method , based on adjacency of $ v_{n-1}$, $C_2$ can be divided.

All vertices which are not adjacent to $ v_{n-1}$ create a sub-graph $C_3$.

All vertices adjacent to $ v_{n-1}$create a sub-graph $, C_4 $. 
    In general , $ C_{2y} $ is a graph and can be divided/ partitioned  in to 2 sub graphs $ C_{2y+1},  C_{2y+2} $ .

This method individualizes a set of $k$ vertices where $k< log_2(n)$.

**Question:**
                   **Does   above individualization exist in current literature ?**

Initially, I thought , it is a variant of $k$ dim Wl method.

**Motivation :** Graph Isomorphism.

*PS: Feel free to edit the post. let me know if it is still unclear.*

Comment: It seems that the result of your individualization process depends very sensitively on the order in which vertices are listed, e.g., which vertex serves as $v_n$ to begin the process. Under these circumstances, I don't see the relevance of this to the graph isomorphism problem, and therefore I doubt that the process has been studied, unless it was for an entirely different purpose.

Comment: @AndreasBlass , Thanks for you comment, it was helpful. I was trying to use the above process for Graph Isomorphism testing with WL method. I have been asked where I got it. It is suspected, that the process exists which I have expressed \written in an elementary way. I 'believe'  this process can help to improve the upper bound.